# Golang array of string inside struct

Tags: go

Im using the following struct

```
type Str struct {
    Info    string
    Command string
}
```

And to fill data inside of it Im doing the following which works.

```
    return []Str{
        {"info from source",
            "install && run"},
    }
```

Now I need to change the command to array

```
type Str struct {
    Info    string
    Command []string
}
```

And provide each of the commands("install" and "run")  in new entry in the array, how can I do that

when I try with

```
return []Str{
    {"info from source",string[]{
        {"install},  {"run"}},
}
```

I got erorr of missing type literal, any idea what Im  doing wrong

Comment: I also do that mistake, inserting [] after type (as I spell it as type array). Instead spelling as "slice of type" helps to write as []string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
return []Str{
    {"info from source", []string{"install", "run"}},
}
```